# Merging Lists by Index in Python

Tags: python, list

**Scenario:** I retrieved 3 lists from a N-triples file, and now I am trying to combine them into a single, organized list.

**Original format:**

```
+--------+---------+--------+
| 100021 | hasdata | y      |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 100021 | name    | USER1  |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 100021 | extra1  | typer  |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 100021 | extra2  | reader |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 50003  | hasdata | y      |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 50003  | name    | USER2  |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 50003  | extra1  | reader |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 50003  | extra2  | writer |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 50003  | extra3  | coder  |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 30007  | hasdata | n      |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 30007  | name    | 0001   |
+--------+---------+--------+
| 30007  | extra1  | Null   |
+--------+---------+--------+
```

While looping the ntriples file, I produced 3 lists (each is a column of the table above). I am now trying to match them into something like this:

```
+--------+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|        | hasdata | name  | extra1 | extra2 | extra3 |
+--------+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| 100021 | y       | USER1 | typer  | reader |        |
+--------+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| 50003  | y       | USER2 | reader | writer | coder  |
+--------+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| 30007  | extra2  | n     | 0001   | Null   |        |
+--------+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

So far, I used the function:

```
def listOfTuples(l1, l2, l3): 
    return list(map(lambda x, y, z:(x,y, z), l1, l2, l3))
```

But this only gave me a direct merge of correspondent items.

**Question:** I know it is possible to loop through the lists and get the matching items and build an array/dataframe manually. My question is is there any function or package that can do this automatically and in a less convoluted way?

**Obs:** I already have a way to produce the dataframe by looping manually. I just wanted to know if there is another more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want a dataframe, so I'll operate on the assumption that pandas operations are acceptable.

I'm also assuming that the symbols are only you formatting, and not part of the actual data file (in the future, those sort of decorators are unnecessary and even detrimental for these type of questions)

Using your given data, I create a df (`pd.read_csv` or some such) then pivot it

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   100021  hasdata y
1   100021  name    USER1
2   100021  extra1  typer
3   100021  extra2  reader
4   50003   hasdata y
5   50003   name    USER2
6   50003   extra1  reader
7   50003   extra2  writer
8   50003   extra3  coder
9   30007   hasdata n
10  30007   name    0001
11  30007   extra1  Null

df.pivot(index='col1',columns='col2',values='col3')

col2    extra1  extra2  extra3  hasdata name
col1                    
30007   Null    NaN     NaN     n       0001
50003   reader  writer  coder   y       USER2
100021  typer   reader  NaN     y       USER1
```

Comment: Yup, I forgot about pivot. It does work, but my issue is that my ntriples file is 6.5gb large, so that is the reason I was trying to work with lists.

Comment: That makes sense, but would have been good detail to have as a constraint in your original question

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you have a list which has tuple elements with a size of three objects, and you want to put them in another tuple  You can use `zip` to achieve this.

```
result = list(zip(list1, zip(*[(l1,l2,l3) for i in list1])))
```

Comment: I Just tried this, but either I don|t know how to implement this properly or I do not know how to interpret the result. All i get is: <zip object at 0x000001CC566F8208>

Comment: @DGMS89 oh sorry, you have to use list(zip), fixed that.

Comment: @DGMS89 and another thing that I have assumed is that your l1,l2,l3 are values (from what I have seen from your code), if they are lists, a minor tweak should be made.

Comment: I will try to work on this. The only thing I am not getting, is that the match of items should be in two levels (list 1 and list 2) to set a result (list 3), but with zip I was only able to index by list 1 so far.

Comment: @DGMS89 can you elborate in your `listOfTuples` function, what are l1,l2,l3? and what are x, y, z. What I understood from your question was that you have a list of tuples(your n_triplets) for each row.